# Why fadeout effect for view did't work?

Tags: macos, animation, nsview

I add to the scrollview my view with content as a documenView and use this code to fadeout my documentView:

```
- (IBAction)deleteAllRules:(id)sender {

    NSViewAnimation * deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation;
    NSRect viewRect;
    NSMutableDictionary* animDict;

    // Create the attributes dictionary
    animDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    viewRect = listOfRulesView.frame;

    // Specify which view to modify.
    [animDict setObject:listOfRulesView forKey:NSViewAnimationTargetKey];

    // Specify the starting position of the view.
    [animDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:viewRect] forKey:NSViewAnimationStartFrameKey];

    // Shrink the view from its current size to nothing.
    NSRect viewZeroSize = listOfRulesView.frame;
    viewZeroSize.size.width = 0;
    viewZeroSize.size.height = 0;
    [animDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:viewZeroSize] forKey:NSViewAnimationEndFrameKey];

    // Set this view to fade out
    [animDict setObject:NSViewAnimationFadeOutEffect forKey:NSViewAnimationEffectKey];

    // Create the view animation object.
    deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:[NSArray
                                                               arrayWithObjects:animDict, nil]];
    // Set some additional attributes for the animation.
    [deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation setDuration:1.5];    // One and a half seconds.
    [deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseIn];
    [deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation setDelegate:self];

    // Run the animation.
    [deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation startAnimation];

    // The animation has finished, so go ahead and release it.
    [deleteListOfRulesViewAnimation release];

}
```

but view hide with out fadeout effect. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended to use Core Animation for 10.5+ code.

The simplest way to use Core Animation is to use the animator proxy. For example you can do the fade out effect by animating the alpha value of the view :

```
[[myView animator] setAlpaValue:0.0f]
```

You can change the animation duration using:

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.4f]
```